# Memory space allocation and deallocation implementation using a linked List

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, linked-list

This is a homework question in relation to memory management implementation using linked lists.
Each memory process requests of a particular size of memory that must be contiguously large enough to fit the memory and then allocate the process.When a job terminates,its allowed memory becomes free.
Here's my java code for this:

```
 public class PartitionNode{
    int beginAddress;
    int endAddress;
    boolean holeFree;
    int processId;
    PartitionNode next;

public PartitionNode(int begin,int end){
     beginAddress=begin;
     endAddress=end;
     holeFree=true;
     processId=-1;
     next=null;


}

public PartitionNode(){}
public PartitionNode(int begin,int end,int i){
    beginAddress=begin;
    endAddress=end;
    holeFree=false;
    processId=i;

}
```

}

```
public class Partition{
    private  PartitionNode head;
    public PartitionNode current;

public  int begin;
public int end;
public PartitionNode newPartition;
private Partition(int beginAddress,int endAddress){
    head=new PartitionNode(beginAddress,endAddress);
    begin=beginAddress;
    end=endAddress;
    current=head;
}

public void addProcess(int size,int id){
    if((current.endAddress-current.beginAddress>=size)&& current.holeFree==true){
        newPartition=new PartitionNode(current.beginAddress,current.beginAddress+size-1,id);
        current.next=newPartition;
        newPartition.next=refresh();

        System.out.println("beginAddress"+newPartition.beginAddress);
        System.out.println("endAddress"+newPartition.endAddress);

    }

}

 public void print(){
    PartitionNode temp=head;


    while(temp.next!=null){
        System.out.println(temp.processId);
        temp=temp.next;
    }
 }


public   PartitionNode refresh(){
    current=new PartitionNode(newPartition.endAddress+1,end);
        return current;

}
public void deleteProcess(int process){
    PartitionNode temp=head;
    PartitionNode temp2=head;

    while(temp.next!=null){
        if(temp.processId==process){

            temp2.next=temp.next;
            break;
        }
        temp2=temp;
        temp=temp.next;
    }

}



public static void main (String args[]){
    Partition p=new Partition(300,3000);
    p.addProcess(500,1);

    p.addProcess(800,2);

    p.addProcess(400,3);
    p.deleteProcess(2);
    p.print();


}


}
```

If I do the processes  as

- Allocate P1 500k
- Allocate P2 800k
- Allocate P3 400k
- Terminate P2
- Allocate P4 100k

according to my code 100 k of space would be allocated for P4  within the remaining space of 1700-3000 (Assuming total memory size is 3000k) even though the space earlier accommodated by P2 is now free and therefore P4 could be included in the space of earlier p2.

How can I make it to work so that P4 is added to the now free space of P2

Comment: I suggest you use a debugger and/or print out the state of the partition after each operation.  This will show you where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your deleteProcess method removes the reference to the PartitionNode object you want to delete thus allowing the garbage collector to free the memory. However Java's garbage collector does not guarantee that this will happen immediately or within a set period of time after all references to the object are deleted.

What this means for you is that the memory is not freed and you cannot control when this will happen.

I hope i understood your question and this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding a new slot to end of the linklist you have to search for free slot. Refer to "searchSlotAndInsert" where we searching for free slot.

Try below code:

```
    public class Partition {
        private PartitionNode head;
        public PartitionNode current;

        public int begin;
        public int end;
        public PartitionNode newPartition;

        private Partition(int beginAddress, int endAddress) {
            head = new PartitionNode(beginAddress, endAddress);
            begin = beginAddress;
            end = endAddress;
            current = head;
        }

        public void addProcess(int size, int id) {
            boolean isProcessInserted = searchSlotAndInsert(size, id); 
            if (!isProcessInserted && (current.endAddress - current.beginAddress >= size)
                    && current.holeFree == true) {
                newPartition = new PartitionNode(current.beginAddress,
                        current.beginAddress + size - 1, id);
                current.next = newPartition;
                newPartition.next = refresh();
            } 
        }

        public void print() {
            PartitionNode temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                System.out.println(temp.next.processId);
                temp = temp.next.next;
            }
        }

        public PartitionNode refresh() {
            current = new PartitionNode(newPartition.endAddress + 1, end);
            return current;
        }

        public void deleteProcess(int process) {
            PartitionNode temp = head;
            PartitionNode temp2 = head;
            while (temp.next != null) {
                if (temp.processId == process) {
                    temp2.next = temp.next.next;
                    if(temp2.next == null){
                        current = temp2;
                    }
                    break;
                }
                temp2 = temp;
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
//Search for free slot
        public boolean searchSlotAndInsert(int size, int id){
            PartitionNode temp2 = head;
            PartitionNode temp = head.next;
            while (temp != null) {
                if (temp2.beginAddress != temp.beginAddress) {
                    break;
                }
                temp2 = temp.next;
                temp = temp.next.next;
            } 
            if(temp != null && temp.beginAddress-temp2.beginAddress >= size){
                PartitionNode newPartition1 = new PartitionNode(temp2.beginAddress,
                        temp2.beginAddress + size - 1, id);
                temp2.next = newPartition1;
                PartitionNode temp3 = new PartitionNode(newPartition1.endAddress + 1, end);
                newPartition1.next = temp3;
                temp3.next = temp;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Partition p = new Partition(300, 4000);
            p.addProcess(500, 1);
            p.addProcess(800, 2);
            p.addProcess(400, 3);
            p.deleteProcess(2);
            p.deleteProcess(3);
            p.addProcess(1100, 4);
            p.addProcess(800, 5);
            p.addProcess(100, 6);
            p.deleteProcess(1);
            p.deleteProcess(5);
            p.deleteProcess(6);
            p.addProcess(900, 7);
            p.addProcess(100, 8);
            p.addProcess(500, 9);
            p.print();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  It would be best if you could expand upon your answer and provide an explanation instead of just code.